# Let $(p,q)$ be two natural numbers, how quickly compute the sign of $10^p-2^q$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, numerical-methods

Assume I have two natural numbers $(p,q)$, and I would like to compute the sign 
of $10^p-2^q$. Are there any methods that void determining the digits of $10^p$ and $2^q$ and are nevertheless exact?

For example using a limited precission numeric $r = log_{10}(2) + ε$ value wouldn't do practically for all pairs $(p,q)$, since the sign $p - q*r$ might differ from the sign $10^p-2^q$.

What are the fastest methods?

**Edit:** Here is the problem that led me to the above. From The Hitchhiker's Guide
to the Galaxy we know the answer is always 42. So can we solve this one:

```
Find n, k in N, e in R:

log(2)*10^(n+2) = k*100 + 42 + e  &&  0 <= e < 1
```

The thing is extremely annoying...

Comment: Effectively, whatever you do will compute a sufficiently high-precision value for $r$, so there isn't a clever method that doesn't also do that.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that we know $r$ to a lot of digits, and $p$ would have to exceed $10$ to the power of that many digits before we couldn't use this "limited-precision" value, so it would go a long way before causing a problem.

Comment: Finally, remember that we *have* methods for computing $\log_{10} 2$ to arbitrary precision, and I suspect that would be the fastest way to answer these questions when $p$ is very close to $q \log_{10} 2$.

Comment: Maybe [generalized continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction) may be used for $\log 2$ and $\log 10$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. It's clear that the sign of your expression is strictly positive if and only if $\frac{p}{q} > \frac{\log(2)}{\log(10)}$ - does this do the trick?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi But you might need a lot of precision in those logarithms for some pairs $(p.q)$, which may mean lots of computation.

Comment: You might like that finding regarding the number 42 and the great number-theorist G.H.Hardy interesting... see http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/GHHArdyAndTheNumber42.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have a start.

We want to compare
$10^p$ with
$2^q$.

Since
$10^3 < 2^{10}$,
$10^p
< 2^{10p/3}
$,
so if
$10p/3 < q$,
or
$10p < 3q$,
then
$10^p < 2^q$.

Similarly,
but less closely,
$10^4 > 2^{13}$.
Therefore
$10^p
\gt 2^{13p/4}
$,
so if
$13p/4 >q$,
or
$13p > 4q$,
then
$10^p > 2^q$.

These are the easy steps.
What has not yet been decided is when
$13p/4 \le q \le 10p/3
$.

Since we can assume that
$q > p$,
dividing by
$2^p$,
we want to compare
$5^p$ with
$2^{q-p}
=2^n$
where
$n = q-p$
so
$9p/4 \le n \le 7p/3$.

Taking the
$p$-th root,
we want to compare
$5$
with
$2^{n/p}
=2^r$
where
$r = n/p = (q-p)/p$
and
$9/4 \le r \le 7/3$.

As this point,
we seem to have to
look at real numbers
instead of integers,
since we want to compare
$\log_2 5 $
with 
$r
=n/p
=(q-p)/p
$.

What we need are
increasingly accurate
lower and upper
rational bounds for
$\log_2 5$.
If these are
$u < \log_2 5
< v$,
we want to compare
$u$ and $v$
with $n/p$.

If
$v < n/p$,
then
$\log_2 5 < n/p$
or
$5^p < 2^n$.

If
$u > n/p$,
then
$\log_2 5 > n/p$
or
$5^p > 2^n$.

If
$u \le n/p\le v$,
we can not decide
and have to get
more accurate bounds.

I'll leave it at this.